# How can I reinstall my AMD 880g/sb850 usb driver?

Tags: windows-7, usb, chipset

I have the Asus M4A88TD-M Evo motherboard with the AMD 880g/sb850 chipset and I wanted to use AHCI mode. I activated it in the BIOS and made a change to the Windows 7 registry and I got it working.

I downloaded these drivers from the AMD website:

```
         AMD Chipset Drivers
         AMD AHCI Driver
         AMD USB 3.0 Driver
```

The AHCI driver didn't get updated and my USB driver is updated but now not functional.

Now when I start my PC the mouse isn't working anymore and in Device Manager the USB controller is signed with a yellow exclamation mark.

How can I fix my USB controller so that I can use my mouse again? I've tried to remove the USB driver in the device driver and run the hardware detection but it just reinstalls the USB driver with the yellow exclamation mark.

When I install the driver it asks me to reboot and after the reboot my mouse isn't working. When I try to uninstall it it says nothing is installed.

Output of `lspci -vt` under Linux:

```
 [0000:00]-+-00.0  Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] RS880 Host Bridge
         +-02.0-[01]--+-00.0  NVIDIA Corporation GF106 [GeForce GTS 450]
         |            \-00.1  NVIDIA Corporation GF106 High Definition Audio Controller
         +-07.0-[02]----00.0  VIA Technologies, Inc. VT6315 Series Firewire Controller
         +-11.0  Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 SATA Controller [AHCI mode]
         +-12.0  Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 USB OHCI0 Controller
         +-12.2  Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 USB EHCI Controller
         +-13.0  Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 USB OHCI0 Controller
         +-13.2  Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 USB EHCI Controller
         +-14.0  Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI SBx00 SMBus Controller
         +-14.2  Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI SBx00 Azalia (Intel HDA)
         +-14.3  Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 LPC host controller
         +-14.4-[03]----05.0  Atheros Communications Inc. AR5413/AR5414 Wireless Network Adapter [AR5006X(S) 802.11abg]
         +-14.5  Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 USB OHCI2 Controller
         +-16.0  Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 USB OHCI0 Controller
         +-16.2  Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 USB EHCI Controller
         +-18.0  Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] Family 10h Processor HyperTransport Configuration
         +-18.1  Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] Family 10h Processor Address Map
         +-18.2  Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] Family 10h Processor DRAM Controller
         +-18.3  Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] Family 10h Processor Miscellaneous Control
         \-18.4  Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] Family 10h Processor Link Control
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should go to Asus's website for updated drivers.

There is a USB 3.0 Host Controller Driver V2.0.4.0 for Windows 32/64bit XP & 32/64bit Vista& 32/64bit 7 available.

I have always gone to the Mobo manufacture site for drivers and have had the most positive results that way. Everything is laid out specifically for the board.

[Asus site](http://support.asus.com/download.aspx?SLanguage=en&p=1&s=24&m=M4A88TD-M%20EVO/USB3&os=&hashedid=GieCoWs1Eigeef6i)

Answer (score 0):

When I installed the motherboard drivers for my AMD970 & SB950 chipset, I had to do multiple things, to get Win 7 going.

First I had to make sure that the mouse was not in any of the USB 3.0 ports, who have a blue color instead of white.
And then I installed the chipset drivers from the Catalyst package. 
 After a boot, the mouse was live and I could then more easily install the rest of the drivers, as it was not that easy without a mouse working.

I have a separate driver for the USB 3.0 ports, if you have only USB 3.0 ports it might be necessary to install both the chipset driver and the USB 3.0 driver before you get your mouse working.